# Relacionar Check Boxes com Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, banco-de-dados, .net

Estou com um projeto onde eu tenho que colocar ocorrências. Este é um projeto de uma escola. Então as ocorrências seriam assim: Uma ocorrência seria uma advertência ou uma suspensão, e as suas causas, ou seja, bagunçou em sala, xingou professor, não fez dever etc. A minha dúvida é: Como fazer pra relacionar esses elementos ? Digo o radio button com o check box. Lembrando que eu já tenho o model do aluno, e como relacionar isso no aluno ? Digo, criando outra tabela no banco e relacionando as duas ? Ou dá pra fazer isso em uma tabela só e como popular ela do jeito certo ? E como que eu posso colocar um status nessa ocorrência ? Digo se o já foi resolvida ou não a ocorrência, tipo: Status -> Pendente, pra saber que ainda não resolveu, e -> Resolvido, se já foi resolvida a ocorrência. Lembrando que eu quero que seja editável também essa ocorrência.

Resumindo eu queria que cadastrasse e depois exibisse, caso queira editar também seja possível e deletar também !

Aqui o código que eu coloquei(HTML: usando bootstrap cllapse):

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#ocorrencias">
                Ocorrências do Aluno
            </a>
        </h4>
    </div>

    <div id="ocorrencias" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="radio-inline">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value="Advertencia" id="Advertencia" />
                    Advertência
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" value="Suspensao" id="Suspensao" />
                    Suspensão por: <input type="text" class="col-xs-1" name="dias" id="dias"/> dias.
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="atividade" id="atividade" value="" checked>
                    Estar deixando de fazer as atividades discentes ou não ter concluido a mesma
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="material" id="material" value="">
                    Não trazer o material necessario para as aulas do dia
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="uniforme" id="uniforme" value="">
                    Não estar devidamente uniformizado
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="conversa" id="conversa" value="">
                    Estar conversando excessivamente em sala de aula
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="atrapalhando" id="atrapalhando" value="">
                    Estar brincando e atrapalhando os colegarr em sala de aula
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="atividadesDocentes" id="atividadesDocentes" value="">
                    Estar impedindo as atividades docentes
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="brincando" id="brincando" value="">
                    Estar com brincadeira de mau gosto na escola <input type="text" name="motivo" id="motivo"/>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="aula" id="aula" value="">
                    Estar frequentemente "matando aula" ou chegando atrasado
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="fugindo" id="fugindo" value="">
                    Ter saído da escola sem autorização, fugiu ás <input type="text" name="hora" id="hora"/>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="foraDeSala" id="foraDeSala" value="">
                    Estar fora da sala de aulas <input type="text" name="fora" id="fora"/>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="agredido" id="agredido" value="">
                    Ter agredido, faltado com o devido respeito aos colegas <input type="text" name="respeito" id="respeito" />
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="respeito" id="respeito" value="">
                    Ter faltado com respeito ao professor
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="equipamentos" id="equipamentos" value="">
                    Estar usando equipamentos eletro-eletrônicos em sala de aula <input type="text" name="equipamentos" id="equipamentos" />
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="outros" id="outros" value="">
                    Outros <textarea name="outros" id="outros"></textarea>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-success" />
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

E aqui o meu model(Aluno.cs):

```
 public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome do aluno é obrigatório")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Aluno")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Pai")]
    public string NomePai { get; set; }

   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome da mãe é obrigatório")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome da Mãe")]
    public string NomeMae { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Responsável")]
    public string NomeResponsavel { get; set; }

   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "O endereço é obrigatório")]
    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "O endereço deve ter no mínimo 10 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "A data de nascimento é obrigatória")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O ano letivo deve ter no máximo 4 caracteres: AAAA ")]
    [Display(Name = "Ano Letivo")]
    public string AnoLetivo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o ano que o aluno está cursando")]
    public int Ano { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a turma do aluno")]
    public string Turma { get; set; }

   // [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o numero da turma")]
    public int Numero { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "informe o turno")]
    public string Turno { get; set; }

    //[Required(ErrorMessage="O telefone é obrigatório")]
    [Display(Name="Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Telefone Alternativo")]
    public string TelefoneContato { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Telefone Responsável")]
    public string TelefoneResponsavel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }
```

Se for preciso depois coloco o meu controller !

Comment: Caso alguém tenha outra resposta, fique a vontade ! Ideias são sempre bem vindas !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu faria assim:

- Um Model de Ocorrências para o *Aluno* (sugestão de nome: **AlunoOcorrencia**) de cardinalidade N, ou seja, seu modelo de *Aluno* ficaria assim:

  ```
  public class Aluno {
      /* Aqui vão todas as propriedades já mencionadas */

      public virtual ICollection<AlunoOcorrencia> AlunoOcorrencias {get;set;}
  }
  ```
- Um Model *AlunoOcorrencia*:

  ```
  public class AlunoOcorrencia {
      [Key]
      public long AlunoOcorrenciaId {get;set;}

      [Required]
      public TipoOcorrencia TipoOcorrencia {get;set;}

      /* Coloque aqui mais propriedades */
  }
  ```
- *TipoOcorrencia* seria um *Enum*:

  ```
  namespace SeuProjeto.Enums {
      public enum TipoOcorrencia {
          BaguncaSala, 
          DesacatoProfessor,
          NaoEntregouDeverDeCasa
      }
  }
  ```
- *TipoOcorrencia* na *View* (Razor):

  ```
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoOcorrencia, Enums.TipoOcorrencia.BaguncaSala) Bagunça em Sala
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.DesacatoProfessor, Enums.TipoOcorrencia.BaguncaSala) Desacato ao Professor
  @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.NaoEntregouDeverDeCasa, Enums.TipoOcorrencia.BaguncaSala) Não Entregou Dever de Casa
  ```
- `CheckBoxes` na *View* (Razor):

  `CheckBoxes` já fica bem mais complicado de colocar, mas é possível usando um componente chamado [MvcCheckBoxList](http://nuget.org/packages/MvcCheckBoxList). Pra resposta não ficar extensa demais, vou passar o link de um tutorial pra você verificar se o componente atende sua necessidade: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/613785/How-to-Use-CheckBoxListFor-With-ASP-NET-MVC

Comment: Ali na classe AlunoOcorrencia teria que ter também a ocorrência, digo: Suspensão ou Advertência também né ? E na suspensão, por quantos dias que o aluno foi suspenso. E eu tava mexendo com enum, e tive muito problema. E como que eu faria pra mostrar o que já foi cadastrado da ocorrência ? Outra tela com os valores ?

Comment: Que problemas com Enum você teve? O que eu tinha imaginado é que um registro da ocorrência teria todos os valores sobre a ocorrência. Aí seria o caso de você trabalhar melhor esse modelo.

Comment: Cara, na hora de pópular uns dropdowns(ano, turno e turma que tem ali no model) ele funcionava, cadastrava, tudo numa boa. Só que quando eu queria editar os dados, na hora de carregar os dados salvos, os enums voltavam com valores padrões e seu eu num mudasse, salvava a edição com os valores padrões. E isso atrapalhava demais, porque o usuário tinha que ta mudando isso toda hora.

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Tem coisa errada nos componentes que vão em tela. Como isto estava sendo feito?

Comment: eu carregava os enums nas view e jogava os valores nos combos. Só que quando editava, num sei o que eu fazia que os valores que eram cadastrados, não retornavam e sim os valores padrão.

Comment: Possivelmente porque o ModelBinder não estava reconhecendo os valores. Acho que o ideal seria resolver isso em separado. Sugiro você fazer uma outra pergunta mostrando como você faz pra popular esses valores em *View*.

Comment: Eu fiz uma lista, e no controller edit, eu puxei os valores selecionados pelo usuário. Mas voltando a pergunta aqui, como que eu faria pra relacionar os radio buttons e check boxes e popular nesses models e grava no banco ? Teria uma pista de como que eu faço ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Vou editar a pergunta pra você.

Comment: OK. Tranquilo ! Vou editar a pergunta só na parte do html, porque inverti os radios e checkes

Comment: @ÉrikThiago Veja agora.

Comment: To vendo aqui o link. Ficou complicado demais hein ? E outra, então eu teria que fazer outras views pra poder mostrar o que já foi cadastrado e alterar, listar ou remover ? E aqui num poderia usar o CheckBoxFor não ?

Comment: @ÉrikThiago O normal é usar uma *partial* (no MVC normalmente ela é nomeada "_CreateOrEdit.cshtml"). Aí você não precisa fazer uma *View* detalhada. Basta apenas chamar a *partial*.

Comment: Cara será que podia me ajudar no bate papo ?

Answer (score 1):

Eu faria assim:

```
public class Aluno
{
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O nome do aluno é obrigatório")]
    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Aluno")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Pai")]
    public string NomePai { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome da Mãe")]
    public string NomeMae { get; set; }

    [MinLength(3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter no mínimo 3 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Nome do Responsável")]
    public string NomeResponsavel { get; set; }

    [MinLength(10, ErrorMessage = "O endereço deve ter no mínimo 10 caracteres")]
    [Display(Name = "Endereço")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [Display(Name = "Data de Nascimento")]
    public DateTime DataDeNascimento { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(4, ErrorMessage = "O ano letivo deve ter no máximo 4 caracteres: AAAA ")]
    [Display(Name = "Ano Letivo")]
    public string AnoLetivo { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o ano que o aluno está cursando")]
    public int Ano { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe a turma do aluno")]
    public string Turma { get; set; }

    public int Numero { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "informe o turno")]
    public string Turno { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Alternativo")]
    public string TelefoneContato { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Telefone Responsável")]
    public string TelefoneResponsavel { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Foto")]
    public string Foto { get; set; }

    //adicionado ao seu exemplo a lista e o construtor
    public ICollection<Ocorrencia> Ocorrencias { get; set; }

    public Aluno()
    {
        this.Ocorrencias = new HashSet<Ocorrencia>();
    }
}

public class Ocorrencia
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int AlunoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Aluno Aluno { get; set; }

    public int OcorrenciaTipoId { get; set; }
    public virtual OcorrenciaTipo OcorrenciaTipo { get; set; }

    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    /**outros campos referente as Ocorrencias*/
}

public class OcorrenciaTipo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }

    /**outros campos referente as OcorrenciaTipo*/
}
```

junto com o Model `Aluno.cs`, e como você mesmo relatou dá um certo trabalho com `enum`, e nesse caso poderia ter as modificações em `OcorrenciaTipo` da maneira que desejar.

No caso são duas tabelas a mais para ter esse controle de Ocorrencias no seu sistema .

Comment: Entendi e nessas descrições ai seria respectivamente: Advertencia e Suspensão, e as causas: Bagunça, desrespeito e etc certo ? E como que eu faria isso na view ? Digo view cadastrar, editar, deletar e listar, as ocorrências de determinado aluno, ou seja, o id do aluno ? Teria que fazer outras views e importá-las ?

Comment: Tem n formas de se fazer isso, uma com Tabs no edit do Aluno, outra clicando em algum botão e redirecionado para alguma tela que possa inserir, alterar ou excluir com o Id do Aluno, ai vai mesmo da sua criatividade ... 
Tem a forma normal que ai carrega uma lista de alunos em um select, acredito ser a mais básica mas, também ser a que carrega muitas informações desnecessárias na tela

Comment: Pode se utilizar um JQuery Tabs: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Comment: O que acontece, eu estou colocando a foto e essas informações na parte de detalhes e na parte de remover o aluno né, pra ficar tudo certinho e nas outras telas como cadastrar e editar, só as informações básicas, como nome, foto, entre outras. Pensei em colocar essa parte de ocorrências na tela de detalhes mesmo, pra mostrar os detalhes do aluno em si, ou seja, suas informações, fotos e ocorrências. Seria uma boa colocar a lista de ocorrências lá e importar as views, digo, todas ?

Comment: Pode ser, e ai não precisa mostrar todas as ocorrencias mostre 3 até umas 5 e um link para uma pagina de ocorrencias que mostre todas... eu faria assim

Comment: Poxa que ótimo. Vou tentar assim. Eu até achei legal a parte das tabs, só que como que ia usar elas pra mostrar os dados pra edição ou remoção ? Poderia usar a mesma tab de cadastro pra carregar os dados? E um glyphicon com link pra remover ? Acho melhor importar as views não ? E outra, como fazer pra relacionar ali no html, as duas coisas ? Digo: O aluno levou uma suspensão, por tantos dias, por causa que estava bagunçando em sala de aula...

Comment: Outra coisa, como faço pra colocar o status da ocorrência ?